# Eclipse right click new project preferences

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, contextmenu

Well, honestly, it is a simple question I can't find on eclipse nor google.

I am a lazy dev and want to add the `Maven Project`option to my [right click]->New->(Maven Project). But can't find an option in the preferences. Every Javaproject I create **is** a maven project (DM FTW, YEA!)

In PHPStorm I can simply add/edit an entry in a config section and I am done. It gets added to any "New" context.

Can I do something like that in eclipse? Add completely new "New..." entries to create a templated new file type and (the original topic) can I add another menu entry without writing a plugin?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open eclipse, then go to `Window` menu, select `Customize perspective...`

a windows appears. it has for tabs.

- Tool bar visiblity
- Menu visiblity
- Command Groups Availablity
- Shortcuts

select `Menu visiblity` tab, it will shows all menus with tree view.

[image]

then expand tree view of `File` then do same for the `New` which is sub tree of `File`.

[image]

now select All of those project types that you want, then click `Ok`.

Comment: Perfect! Nothing more to add!

Answer (score 0):

The concept is:

**new** means creating a bare project begining from zero, 
**adding** means import some project that you/other have/has started...

in eclipse **import** is the menu you need to click to, then **maven**, then select the proj option the best fits you...

[image]

Comment: That isn't my intention.

Normally, I go to File -> New -> Others... and there I click Maven -> Maven project.

I want to know, if I can add it the right click context menu when I click my working set.